# making a graphic of two variables

Tags: plotting

I have a two variables system (let say $c$ and $s$ for this variables) and as the system is too complicated to solve analytically, I try to find corresponding values for these two variables numerically.

```
u[c_] := c^(1 - σ)/(1 - σ)
h[s_] := (2 hbar)/(1 + Exp[η (1 - s/sbar)])
d[s_] := (b s^2)/2
```

with the following parameters ;

```
paramFinal = {σ -> 0.55, ρ -> 0.0127, g -> 0.05, sbar -> 95, η -> 3.5, hbar -> 0.01, α -> 0.01, b -> 0.0001, priceadap -> 0.0006,δ -> 0.1, γ -> 2, χ -> 0.025, ϕ -> 0.2, ω -> 0.2, β -> 0.8};
```

I write the equation from which I try to find the corresponding values for variables $c$ and $s$.

```
l[c_, s_] := -χ - (ρ + h[s]) + h'[s]/(ρ + h[s]) ((u[c] - d[s])/(u'[c]/β)) + d'[s]/(u'[c]/β)
```

In order to find these values, I write ;

```
sol3[i_] := Solve[l[c, i] == 0 /. paramFinal, c]
Table[sol3[i], {i, 0, 10}]
```

So, until this stage, I have no problem. I can find the corresponding values for $c$ for $s$ on the range between $0$ and $10$

But I can not figure out how to represent these points on a plane $(c,s)$. How can I proceed ? I tried to use `ListPlot` but it did not work. 
Any insights or hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{c /. FindRoot[l[c, s] == 0 /. paramFinal, {c, 1}], s}, {s, 0, 30}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
tab = Table[sol3[i], {i, 0, 10}]
```

> {{{c -> 13.6479}}, {{c -> 13.0982}}, {{c -> 12.5768}}, {{c -> 
>       12.0821}}, {{c -> 11.6123}}, {{c -> 11.1661}}, {{c -> 
>       10.7421}}, {{c -> 10.339}}, {{c -> 9.95566}}, {{c -> 
>       9.59094}}, {{c -> 9.24382}}}

```
Last /@ Flatten[tab] // ListPlot
```

[image]